# How do I make Google Sheets run a recursive equation

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want google sheets to run the equation A = 200x + The previous A value in the column. I can't seem to figure out how to do subscripts or get the previous value. Sample data 1:200 2:600 3:1200 4:200 5:3000 etc. I have tried looking up how to write recursive equations on google and only found equations that I don't understand.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add some sample data and show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. P.S. As this is a Google Sheets question, whenever it be possible use A1 notation rather than Y, X variables.

Comment: [does this other question help?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com//questions/143226/creating-a-recursive-formula-in-a-single-cell)

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. "Sample data 1:200 2:600 3:1200 4:200 5:3000 etc.". Would you please advise the correct "answers for each of these values.

Comment: "I have tried looking up how to write recursive equations on google and only found equations that I don't understand." Do you mean that you, yourself, do not know how to calculate a recursive equation, or that you don't understand how to execute a recursive equation in Google Sheets? Would you please provide references for the equations that you found.

Comment: Your post as written is not clear. We would need to see actual data in actual ranges against your manually-entered expected results and an explanation of how those results (for at least a handful of rows) was derived. The most efficient means of sharing everything at once is to simple provide a link to a spreadsheet that realistically represents both your potential data and your goal.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that if I write the equation once using the terms in my case =c6 + (200 * a7) I can drag the square at the bottom of the cell and google sheets will repeat the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, you may avoid recursion.
Just use formula `=((ROW()*ROW() + ROW())*100)`

[image]

That is `(x² + x) * 100` where x is the number of row